# PODAM Implementing a data provider strategy for Generic classes

Tags: java, jemos-podam

I am using the PODAM library to generate dummy data into my POJO classes. I ran into an issue while doing that when the class has a Generic class type variables. For example:

```
public class MyClassToBeFilledWithPodam{
  List<MyGenericClass> statusList;
  // standard getters and setters
}
```

And `MyGenericClass` is as below,

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    protected int status;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

When populating the `MyClassToBeFilledWithPodam` class with PODAM, the Following exception gets thrown.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.MyGenericClass is missing generic type arguments, expected [T], provided []
        at uk.co.jemos.podam.typeManufacturers.TypeManufacturerUtil.fillTypeArgMap(TypeManufacturerUtil.java:200)
        at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojoInternal(PodamFactoryImpl.java:491)
        at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:964)
        at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.fillCollection(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1230)
        at uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.resolveCollectionValueWhenCollectionIsPojoAttribute(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1080)
        ... 56 more
```

So far what I did was to ignore this field while populating and then populating the generic object separately like below.

```
class MyTest
{
    @Test
    void testMethod() throws Exception
    {
        MyClassToBeFilledWithPodam myClassTobeFilledWithPodam = new MyClassToBeFilledWithPodam();
        PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();

        DefaultClassInfoStrategy classInfoStrategy = DefaultClassInfoStrategy.getInstance();
        classInfoStrategy.addExcludedField( MyClassToBeFilledWithPodam.class, "statusList" );
        factory.setClassStrategy( classInfoStrategy );

        myClassTobeFilledWithPodam = factory.populatePojo( myClassTobeFilledWithPodam ); // Generate class here

        MyGenericClass deleted = factory.manufacturePojo( MyGenericClass.class, String.class ); // T can be anything because all I want is the status value. Therefore I pass String as the type 

        myClassTobeFilledWithPodam.setStatusList( List.of( deleted ) );
    }
}
```

But doing this to all the available classes in the project is impossible. Is there a way to configure PODAM to say that for the Generic classes `MyGenericClass`, use a default value or instruct it to populate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar to it with an arrayList.
Check it out

```
var projectsResponse = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(ArrayList.class, ProjectResponse.class);
    
when(projectService.getProjectsFromAccountId()).thenReturn(projectsResponse);
```

I guess you should try

```
podamFactory.manufacturePojo(MyClassToBeFilledWithPodam.class, DesiredGenericClassType.class);
```